# Run RegEx Over Array and Return New Values in New Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an array of email addresses:

```
var emails = ['first.last@email.com', 'frst.lst@email.com', 'test.name@email.com']
```

I have a regular expressions to strip the last name from the emails:

```
var re = /(?<=[.]).*(?=[\@])/g; //Strips last name from email address.
```

I am trying to strip the last name and create a new array with those so it would look like:

```
[last, lst, name]
```

Here is the code I have tried, but it is not parsing out the last name at all and is just printing out the first and last email address. Any ideas on how I can achieve this? Thanks!

```
function onEdit() {
var re = /(?<=[.]).*(?=[\@])/g;
var emails = ['first.last@email.com', 'frst.lst@email.com', 'test.name@email.com']
const matchVal = emails.filter(value => re.test(value));
Logger.log(matchVal);
}

//Result of above function
//[first.last@email.com, test.name@email.com]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be mapping over the emails and then getting the first match:

```js
const re = /(?<=[.]).*(?=[\@])/g;
const emails = ['first.last@email.com', 'frst.lst@email.com', 'test.name@email.com']
const matchVal = emails.map(value => value.match(re)[0]);
console.log(matchVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are only single email addresses per array entry, you can also get the desired values by splitting on `@`, check if you get back 2 parts

Then split the first part on a dot and then return the last value of that split.

```js
const emails = [
  'first.last@email.com',
  'frst.lst@email.com',
  'test.name@email.com',
  'this.is.a.test.value@test.test.com',
  'hello'
];
const result = emails.map(s => {
  const parts = s.split("@");
  return parts.length === 2 ? parts[0].split(".").pop() : s;
});
console.log(result);
```